# Error on creating a relationship neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to create an new relationship between two nodes and I get the following error. Both nodes exists in the graph.

Cypher-Statement:

```
Match (d:Document{key:'en_29996'}), (u:User{key:'fschm'}) 
CREATE (d)-[:isVisible]->(u) RETURN d
```

Error Message:

```
Position[119749624] requested for high id[119645868], store is ok[true] recovery[false]
```

Version Neo4j 2.1.6 Community

Any Idea? Thanks

Comment: Do you have an index/constraint on both? Can you reproduce it? Can you share the execution plan? (prepend `PROFILE` in Neo4j-Shell). And would you be able to share your database? Please send it with reference to this question to michael at neo4j.org

Comment: Hi Michael,Yes, on both is an index and I can reproduce it. I will try to share the database with you in next days when I am back in Office.